# ERROR: Proxy URL had no scheme. However, URL & Proxies are properly setup

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm getting the error:

urllib3.exceptions.ProxySchemeUnknown: Proxy URL had no scheme, should start with http:// or https://

but the proxies are fine & so is the URL.

```py
            URL = f"https://google.com/search?q={query2}&num=100"
            mysite = self.listbox.get(0)
            headers = {"user-agent": USER_AGENT}

            while True:
                proxy = next(proxy_cycle)
                print(proxy)
                proxies = {"http": proxy, "https": proxy}
                print(proxies)
                resp = requests.get(URL, proxies=proxies, headers=headers)
                if resp.status_code == 200:
                    break
```

Print results:

41.139.253.91:8080

{'http': '41.139.253.91:8080', 'https': '41.139.253.91:8080'}

Comment: The error could not be more clear, could it?  Your proxy must be `http://41.139.253.91:8080`.

Comment: Looks related to https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/5297.  Seems like the OP's method worked in the past but does not with current versions of Python.  The solution there seems to be exactly as @TimRoberts says.

Comment: Yea, it used to work this way, didnt realize I now had to manually add the HTTP:// and https://

Answer (score 2):

On Linux unset http_proxy and https_proxy using terminal on the current  location of your project

```
unset http_proxy

unset https_proxy
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having same issue. I resolved with upgrading requests library in python3 by

```
pip3 install --upgrade requests
```

I think it is related to lower version of requests library conflicting higher version of python3

Comment: requests 2.25.1 shows the error when I set proxies as an IP address. The current-latest version 2.28.2 had no error. thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and setting in my terminal **https_proxy** variable really helped me. You can set it as follows:

```
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy.example.com:8080 
set https_proxy=http://username:password@proxy.example.com:8080
```

Where `proxy.example.com` is the proxy address (in my case it is `localhost`) and 8080 is my port.

You can figure out your username by typing `echo %username%` in your command line. As for the proxy server, on Windows, you need to go to "Internet Options" -> "Connections" -> LAN Settings and tick "Use a proxy server for your LAN". There, you can find your proxy address and port.

**An important note here.** If you're using PyCharm, try first running your script from the terminal. I say this because you may get the same error if you will just run the file by "pushing" the button. But using the terminal may help you get rid of this error.

**P.S.** *Also, you can try to downgrade your pip to 20.2.3 as it may help you too.*